# msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]

Tags: cmd, windows-installer

Hie 
I am trying to run this operation manager code:

```
%WinDir%\System32\msiexec.exe /i path\Directory\MOMAgent.msi /qn 
USE_SETTINGS_FROM_AD={0|1} USE_MANUALLY_SPECIFIED_SETTINGS={0|1} MANAGEMENT_GROUP=MGname 
MANAGEMENT_SERVER_DNS=MSname MANAGEMENT_SERVER_AD_NAME =MSname SECURE_PORT=PortNumber 
ACTIONS_USE_COMPUTER_ACCOUNT={0|1} ACTIONSUSER=UserName ACTIONSDOMAIN=DomainName 
CTIONSPASSWORD=Password
```

I get the following error

```
Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.9200.16384 

msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]

Install Options

</package | /i> <Product.msi>
        Installs or configures a product
    /a <Product.msi>
        Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
    /j<u|m> <Product.msi> [/t <Transform List>] [/g <Language ID>]
        Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
    </uninstall | /x> <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Uninstalls the product
Display Options
    /quiet
        Quiet mode, no user interaction
    /passive
        Unattended mode - progress bar only
    /q[n|b|r|f]
        Sets user interface level
        n - No UI
        b - Basic UI
        r - Reduced UI
        f - Full UI (default)
    /help
        Help information
Restart Options
    /norestart
        Do not restart after the installation is complete
    /promptrestart
        Prompts the user for restart if necessary
    /forcerestart
        Always restart the computer after installation
Logging Options
    /l[i|w|e|a|r|u|c|m|o|p|v|x|+|!|*] <LogFile>
        i - Status messages
        w - Nonfatal warnings
        e - All error messages
        a - Start up of actions
        r - Action-specific records
        u - User requests
        c - Initial UI parameters
        m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
        o - Out-of-disk-space messages
        p - Terminal properties
        v - Verbose output
        x - Extra debugging information
        + - Append to existing log file
        ! - Flush each line to the log
        * - Log all information, except for v and x options
    /log <LogFile>
        Equivalent of /l* <LogFile>
Update Options
    /update <Update1.msp>[;Update2.msp]
        Applies update(s)
    /uninstall <PatchCodeGuid>[;Update2.msp] /package <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Remove update(s) for a product
Repair Options
    /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Repairs a product
        p - only if file is missing
        o - if file is missing or an older version is installed (default)
        e - if file is missing or an equal or older version is installed
        d - if file is missing or a different version is installed
        c - if file is missing or checksum does not match the calculated value
        a - forces all files to be reinstalled
        u - all required user-specific registry entries (default)
        m - all required computer-specific registry entries (default)
        s - all existing shortcuts (default)
        v - runs from source and recaches local package
Setting Public Properties
    [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]

Consult the Windows ® Installer SDK for additional documentation on the command line syntax.

Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Portions of this software are based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.
```

How to get this to work
I am using it in administrator Mode

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the strings that contain the pipe (|) character. It has a special meaning for the command line interpreter. You command would be

```
%WinDir%\System32\msiexec.exe /i path\Directory\MOMAgent.msi /qn 
USE_SETTINGS_FROM_AD="{0|1}" USE_MANUALLY_SPECIFIED_SETTINGS="{0|1}" MANAGEMENT_GROUP=MGname 
MANAGEMENT_SERVER_DNS=MSname MANAGEMENT_SERVER_AD_NAME =MSname SECURE_PORT=PortNumber 
ACTIONS_USE_COMPUTER_ACCOUNT="{0|1}" ACTIONSUSER=UserName ACTIONSDOMAIN=DomainName 
CTIONSPASSWORD=Password
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ORCA to create a transform to store all of those properties and then use command:

```
msiexec /I MOMAgent.msi /QB REBOOT=R TRANSFORMS=MOMAgent.mst
```

This will simplify the command line and keep your password from showing up in logs.